# C# Post requests got broken

Tags: c#, web-services, post, asp.net-core

I have a program, which makes a Post request. This project worked perfectly, but with old versions of `.NETCORE` (1.1) , I've upgraded everything including the framework to `2.1` . Didn't change the code what so ever, no error occurs and it seemed as the change is ok .

Now my Post request is failing (I'll attach only one, but I have about 4 Post requests, everyone of them fails for the same reason)

**EDIT:** I've just tested my Get requests as well, the produce the same error ..

This is my code :

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    Field fld = new Field()
    {
        ...
   };
    ForJSON bodyFormat = new ForJSON()
    {
        ...
    };
    string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(bodyFormat);
    StringContent sc = new StringContent(output, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    try
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic",
                                                                                            Convert.ToBase64String(
                                                                                            Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(
                                                                                                                                       string.Format("{0}:{1}", "XX", "YY"))));
        response = await client.PostAsync("https:...", sc); // It fails here
```

The error message is :

> attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

I've tried googling this error , but every post doesn't seems relavent to me.. They're talking about permissions firewalls and ports, but why would it work in one project and in the other wouldn’t ?

If I try via Postman / my backup of the the project with 1.1 version , then it works .

Why is this happening ? What got broken? Is there maybe a timeout attribute I need to add?

Comment: I assume the request is not visible in the web server log?

Comment: Monitoring the requests using Fiddler or Wireshark might detect what goes wrong.

Comment: You mean in the network tab ? I don’t see anything.. and I don’t know how to monitor the request either

Comment: I mean Fiddler is can be obtained freely from https://www.telerik.com/fiddler or Wrieshark which can be downloaded from https://www.wireshark.org/.

Comment: I don't know how it will help me solve the problem .. Even if I'll succesfuly set everything there, I don't know what I'm looking for , it just doesn't make sense..

Comment: There is a bigish list of breaking changes here: https://github.com/aspnet/announcements/issues?page=1&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+label%3A2.0.0+label%3A%22Breaking+change%22&utf8=%E2%9C%93 but one which I cannot see (might have been dotnet core 1.1) is the change to the default json serializer that will automatically camel-case properties. This might affect the ability of the original service to match the expected action? https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2018/05/05/setting-json-serialization-configuration-at-runtime-on-a-net-core-api/

Comment: That’s interesting.. though it also happens in a get request which has no body , simply getasync(url)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

For this error, it is caused by the changes between core 1.1 and core 2.1 that `HttpClientHandler` changes from `WinHttpHandler` to `SocketsHttpHandler`.

For a workaround, you may try to configure a process to use the older HttpClientHandler

```
AppContext.SetSwitch("System.Net.Http.UseSocketsHttpHandler", false);
using (var client = new HttpClient())
```

Reference:[Networking Performance](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/2.1/2.1.0.md#networking-performance).

Bug tracking: [.NET Core 2.1 SocketsHttpHandler proxy authentication using Windows auth is broken #30166](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/30166#issuecomment-395489603)

Comment: Works perfectly ! Thank you ! I don’t know how much time I would have needed to figure this out. Do I need to set it once in my project? Or before each call? (Different files)

Comment: @Yossi just need to set it once.